# How is the sample 3D image of Knee is created?

Tags: image3d

The sample 3D image of knee in Mathematica is the MRI of Markus van Almsick(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1ot5MltxM8&spfreload=1).

The corresponding image dimension is {128, 128, 128}.

However, normally MRI consists of 20-25 2D slices. If this is so for the sample knee data set also, I would like to know how this image was re-sized with the above mentioned dimensions?

Comment: `ImageResize` probably? I don't see why the number of images that you have would cause a problem. Did you see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95569/how-to-create-a-3d-model-based-on-mri-cross-sections) question?

Comment: I have seperate image slices but I want to have my 3D image containing all the three views (sagittal, axial and coronal) as there are for the sample knee image.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106151/9490) and [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100210/9490) for some possibilities

Comment: @JasonB In those two answers they have reconstructed the 3d image along one direction. That I can do. But I cannot combine all the three views in these ways. I'm sure the original 3D knee image is not created in this way. Because I can clearly see all the three views in that image.

Comment: @Majis - I don't fully understand.  I would (naively perhaps) think that if you had enough 2D slices along one axis, then the reconstructed solid would be  the same regardless of which axis it is.  Is it possible for me to download the images you have so that I could get a better feel for what you are saying?  I want to see how the 3D objects you create from the different views differ from each other

Comment: @JasonB Here is a link (http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/) where you can get the dataset under the alias name KNIX.

Comment: @Majis, I had already tried that site when I was going for an answer here, but the downloads from that site seem to start and then stall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To whom it may concern,

as far as I recall, the MRI data of my knee were obtain at the TU Eindhoven more than 12 years ago. The acquisition returned the isotropic volume as is. I assume, that in the academic setting we had sufficient time to generate a dense volume instead of a sparse stack of slices.

-- Markus

Comment: Thanks Markus for your kind information. That's what I wanted to know.